# Check if object is Array of instance of specific object in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have a simple class in Node JS

```
class Animal {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
      // more fields ...
    }
}

let objects = [];
objects.push(new Animal('Dog'));
objects.push(new Animal('Cat'));
objects.push(new Animal('Dinosaur'));
console.log(objects);
```

What's the best way to check if this array is **instanceof** `Animal` objects , without looping over and checking `instanceof` of each element ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. `check if this array is instanceof Animal objects` Do you mean `check if this array only contains instanceof Animal objects` ?

Comment: @ikhvjs: Exactly!

Comment: Then, you still need to loop over all elements in the array for checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
class Animal {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
      // more fields ...
    }
}

let objects = [];
objects.push(new Animal('Dog'));
objects.push(new Animal('Cat'));
objects.push(new Animal('Dinosaur'));
console.log(objects.every(x => x instanceof Animal));
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this still loops over every item in the array

Comment: Indeed, and it's not possible without looping